# Scatter plot multiple features against one specifc feature in a dataset

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

Edited:

I have a dataset that has 10 features, and a binary classification column.

The dataset looks as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   x1      100 non-null    float64
 1   x2      100 non-null    float64
 2   x3      100 non-null    float64
 3   x4      100 non-null    float64
 4   x5      100 non-null    float64
 5   x6      100 non-null    float64
 6   x7      100 non-null    float64
 7   x8      100 non-null    float64
 8   x9      100 non-null    float64
 9   x10     100 non-null    float64
 10  y       100 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(10), int64(1)
memory usage: 8.7 KB
time: 41.6 ms (started: 2021-12-27 10:30:27 +00:00)
```

I have already plotted these features against one specific feature `x10` in a pair plot. It is shown below:

[image]

However, I want to separate these plots and have multiple scatter plots (`x10` feature against one feature at a time for all other 9 features)

I have written the code below:

```py
# Generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x2': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x3': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x4': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x5': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x6': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x7': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x8': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x9': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'x10': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
    'y': np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)})


# split data into X and y
X = df.iloc[:, :10]

# specifying columns and rows for the plot
X_cols = X.columns
y_rows = ['x10']

# # pair plot
# sns_plot = sns.pairplot(data = df, x_vars=X_cols, y_vars=y_rows, hue = 'y', palette='RdBu')

# multiple scatter plots
for feature in X_cols:
   sns.scatterplot(data = df[feature], x=feature , y='x10', hue = 'y', palette='RdBu')
   plt.show()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ad3cca752a2e> in <module>()
     26 # multiple scatter plots
     27 for feature in X_cols:
---> 28    sns.scatterplot(data = df[feature], x=feature , y='x10', hue = 'y', palette='RdBu')
     29    plt.show()
     30 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/_core.py in _assign_variables_longform(self, data, **kwargs)
    901 
    902                 err = f"Could not interpret value `{val}` for parameter `{key}`"
--> 903                 raise ValueError(err)
    904 
    905             else:

ValueError: Could not interpret value `x1` for parameter `x`
```

Can I know what I'm doing wrong ? and how can I fix this issue to get my desired output ?

Comment: I suggest providing a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Notice that you have `for feature in cols_X` followed by `x=cols_X[feature]`, which doesn't really make sense. Perhaps simply want `x=feature` for the second part. Also, above that, you don't need `cols_X = X.columns.to_list()`, just `cols_X  = X.columns` is enough. Or even remove that line, and to `for feature in X.columns`, followed by `..., x=feature, ...` in the next line.

Comment: @9769953 I have edited the code as u suggested but now i have the following error ` ValueError: Could not interpret value `address` for parameter `x` `

Comment: Oh, perhaps first change to use `y='time` in your scatterplot call (and remove the line `rows_y = ['time']`: there is no need for it, nor does the `y` parameter need to be a list here).

Comment: @9769953 The same error still exists ..  I will try to provide an updated minimal description to the question

Comment: Yes, please. Include the new traceback as well.

Comment: Hold on: you use `X` to get the columns, but you use `normalized_df` to get the data. Shouldn't you be using `normalized_df` to get the columns? What are `X.columns` and `normalized_df.columns`?

Comment: @9769953 I have edited the example given to be simple and understandable

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example; much appreciated

Comment: There was a third error. Use `sns.scatterplot(data = df, x=feature , y='x10', hue = 'y', palette='RdBu')`. Note `data=df`, not `data=df[feature]`: pass the full dataframe, not a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the original problem and question, there are three mistakes:

- indexing a list with a list item, instead of an index (integer)
- using a list for the y parameter in scatterplot, instead of the column name
- using a specific column for the data parameter, instead of the full dataframe

In addition, there was the needless conversion of the `columns` attribute to a list, then iterating over that list, instead of directly iterating over the `columns` attribute.

The correct code removes the assigments for `cols_X` and `rows_y`, and simplifies the loop to the following:

```
for feature in cols_X.columns:
    sns.scatterplot(data=normalized_df, x=feature, y='time', hue='binary result', palette='RdBu')
    plt.show()
```

(note that `cols_X` has to be a subset, column-wise, of `normalized_df`, so that at least it doesn't include the "time" column, to avoid creating a scatter plot of "time" versus "time". Or that case could be ignored with a quick `if feature == "time": continue` just above the `sns.scatterplot` line.)

---

For comparison, this was the original code:

```
# relatively irrelevant above omitted

cols_X = X.columns.to_list()
rows_y = ['time']

for feature in cols_X:
  sns.scatterplot(data = normalized_df[feature], x= cols_X[feature], y= rows_y , hue = 'binary result', palette='RdBu')
  plt.show()
```